# How to Update and Create at the same time?

Tags: python, django

I would like to create an object and once that is created I want to update an different object, not sure how to do that ?

```
My View:
class CreateUserClassQuestionRecord(CreateAPIView):

    queryset = UserClassQuestionsRecord.objects.all()
    serializer_class = User_Class_Question_RecordSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_inf = UserClassQuestionsRecord.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,
                                                           question__singleclass_id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).all()

        for c in user_inf:
            if c:
                ClassAttempt.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, related_class_id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).update(
                    is_first_time=False)
                Response(status.HTTP_200_OK)

            else:
                pass
```

My json :

```
{
  "is_correct": "True",
  "xp_collected": 10,
  "user": 1,
  "question": 1,
  "selected_answer": 13
}
```

The url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/class-record/new/13/

My Error message:

```
Response.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: The POST request works but when I want to to a Patch which will actually update the ClassAttempt object is does not work .

Comment: I don't understand why you are implementing like this. If you want to update objects during creation of a new object, then you don't need a update view

Comment: Should I just user Create view and the Update the other object anyway ?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, any chance you could post a solution ?

Comment: exactly, use create view abd update objects there or use signals

Comment: just edited the code up, it requires a Response, but once I put a response it says that I'm giving 2 arguments and it receives only 1

Comment: ERROR :Response.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given